# Cannot focus new window in Ruby Watir

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, watir-webdriver

I have done a lot of research before asking this questions but unable to find an answer.

I am trying to automate a website using Ruby Selenium + Webdriver. I am having an issue with the script hanging once new window opened. I am unable to focus on new window or do anything else.

Here is the code that opens up new window:

```
<a id="theField" class="RightTextHeading" onclick="javascript:openTheWindow('someInfo.aspx?type=','300','300');if(window.document.RetValue == '5'){window.parent.LoadinIframe('someStuff.aspx?info=N&amp;Stuff=','Some Data here > Full View','false');}; return false;" href="../MoreStuff/#" style="text-decoration: none;">ClickMe <span class="context"> opens an overlay</span></a>
```

Here is my ruby code:

```
    require 'rubygems'
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

prefs = {
  :download => {
    :prompt_for_download => false,
    :default_directory => '.'
  }
}
client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
#client.timeout = 600 # seconds - default is 60
client.timeout = 30 # seconds - default is 60
d = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, :prefs => prefs, :http_client => client
b = Watir::Browser.new d

saved_cookies = b.cookies.to_a

b.goto'https://somewebsite.com'
begin
    b.iframe(:id => 'iframeBody').a(:id => "somelink").click
rescue
    puts 'Rescue'
end
sleep 2
puts "before"
#if b.window(:title=>"The new window").exists?
   #puts " Test passed. New window opened!"
#else
   #puts " Test Failed! No window found"
#end
#b.window(:title => /The new window/).use do
#b.window.last.use do
#   puts "here" 
#end
#puts b.window(:title => "The new window").exists?
puts b.windows.size
puts "after"

#b.close
```

I have commented out different things I attempted to make this work.
It seems that Ruby just sits and waits after the new window is opened and I do not know how to get it out of the waiting state.

If I do not begin/rescue, the code stops execution until it times out.
When I am trying to rescue I can get control back but still unable to focus on the new window.

Any ideas are appreciated?
Please let me know if you have additional questions.

Thanks,
-Andrey

Comment: Needing a begin-rescue around the clicking of the link seems strange. Are you saying that clicking the link times out or trying to find the new window? It would help to give the result (ie exceptions) of each of the different things you tried.

Comment: After this line: b.iframe(:id => 'iframeBody').a(:id => "somelink").click a new window opens, but Ruby stops. Even regular puts "here" does not do anything.

Comment: "Stops" -- meaning what? Throws an error, or sits in an apparently endless loop? Or something else?

Comment: It opens a new window then sits and for about 30 seconds and after that give me the error: /usr/share/ruby/net/protocol.rb:158:in `rescue in rbuf_fill': Net::ReadTimeout (Net::ReadTimeout)

Comment: Are you using the latest version of selenium-webdriver and the lastest browser driver? The search results I see with the same exception seemed to be resolved by updating to latest.

Answer (score 0):

Im not entirely sure what your trying to do with the test, but the answer on how to do something with the new window is already in your code to some extent

```
#b.window.last.use do
```

should be

```
#b.windows.last.use
```

or

```
@browser.windows.last.use
```

Will have your test start using the new window once it appears.

Depending on what your trying to do, may change where in your code that line should go. But that will let you access and interact with the new window.

Comment: Why should `b.window.last.use do` be `b.windows.last.use`? `use` does accept a block, which allows you to use another window and then automatically switch back to the original window.

Comment: I tried with b.windows.last.use and I still get same issue. The code I posted above works on my dummy website that opens a new window straightforward. I think the issue is with javascript  function waiting for return from the new window and Ruby sits and waits for that as well.

Comment: as I posted above: After this line: b.iframe(:id => 'iframeBody').a(:id => "somelink").click a new window opens, but Ruby stops. Even regular puts "here" does not do anything

Comment: @Justin It seemed he was having an issue doing anything with the new window, so I was trying to suggest a way to access it. The question wasnt clear as to what was actually intended to happen on the new window or what the error specifically was. I most def bow to your expertise, i was just trying offer a way to access his new window, since that is what i gathered from the question was the issue.